# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before numeric constant

Tags: c, macros

I am no macro wizard and I was wondering if there is a way with the _Generic macro to evaluate functions based on constants. As of right now my macro is the following:

```
#define getData(data) _Generic((data), 1: printone, default: printdefault)(data)
```

If this is not possible to do in C I welcome other suggestions! I don't think it is necessary but if more code is needed for the answer to this question then I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The left side of an generic association must<sup>1</sup> consist of a type, or the keyword default.

Since you're hardcoding the constant, there is no reason to not hardcode the type instead:

```
#define getData(data) _Generic((data), int: printone, default: printdefault)(data)
```

The constant 1 will always have the type int, but if you're going to use constants with larger values, that may have other signed types, simply add those types to the _Generic selection.

The following will cover all possible signed integer constants that are formed using *digits only*. In other words, any integer constant, even a large one, like `9223372036854775807` will be covered:

```
#define getData(data) _Generic((data), int: printone, 
                                       long: printonel, 
                                       long long: printonell, 
                                       default: printdefault)(data)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.1.1 Generic selection 1.)
generic-association:
    type-name : assignment-expression
    default : assignment-expression

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! I will try to edit my code accordingly!